# AS3: Voice recognition on ios and android device

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi i just need to know whether we can do voice recognition for ios and android device on AS3. I need to search the text on device based on the voice or audio file. Please anyone let me know the possibilities and the how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, but it's only for Android:
http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2011/12/07/new-actionscript-native-extension-speech-recognition/

Comment: Ya sant, Thanks i too got some link for .android only, i need for ios too. If you have any idea pls let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't found any ANE for iOS, but this might help to create bew one based on it https://github.com/wouterverweirder/AIR-OSX-NSSpeechRecognizerBridge-Extension
Also if your app would work online, you can use Google API for it, check this link, this might help http://nxhoaf.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/speech-to-text-in-action-script-3-part-3/

Comment: Thanks sant. also i found url http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1151  but the link was broken. i need any similar tutorial to do this.